# How can I learn the CSS file path from which an html element is using its styles?

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug

When I select an element on a web page with FireBug's selector, I can easiy see what stye settings it uses.

But how can I learn the source css file's path as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the right of each rule the file name of the CSS file is shown. Point at it, and the tooltip shows you the complete request URL.

Answer (score 3):

You can see this information in Firebug as well as the line number. Place your mouse over the css file reference and the tool tip will give you further details.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's inspector allows you to see which CSS rules are matched in an element (and the source css file). I don't know about firebug though.